# Epson Workforce WF-2630 installation problems on Lubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: lubuntu, printing, epson

I've just bought an Epson printer (Workforce WF-2630) which I have connected to my new laptop running Lubuntu 18.04.3 via wifi (Google Cloud print).

In Cups the print options are very limited. I've installed the suggested drivers in openprinting.org, that are the ones downloadable in Epson web site.

Now, after a "non-linear" installation, all things seem to work (scanning, printing).

The problems are about the options (that are present in windows driver):

- draft and high quality: there is only one possible options, the normal quality, no other settings available.
- double-sided printing: no possible to set (in Windows this possibility is manually managed via software).
- other minor options (borderless printing, better quality in case of photo colour printing etc.).

Moreover, it seems that I can change the settings only with CUPS (system-config-printer), also when the printer is connected with an USB cable...

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Andrea

Comment: nobody can help me?

Comment: nobody buys epson printers??